# Stanford LexicalizedParser throws NPE when using in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, stanford-nlp

I am attempting to use stanford's LexicalizedParser within Spark RDD map function.

The algorithm is roughly like this:

```
val parser = LexicalizedParser.loadModel(englishPCFG.ser.gz)
val parserBroadcast = sparkContext.broadcast(parser) // using Kryo serializer here

someSparkRdd.map { case sentence: List[HasWord] =>
    parserBroadcast.value.parse(sentence) //NPE is being thrown see below
}
```

The reason I would like to instantiate parser once (outside the map) and then just broadcast it, is that the map iterates over almost a million sentences, java garbage collector produces too much overhead and whole processing slows down reasonably.

Upon executing map statement, following NullPointerException is being thrown:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.BaseLexicon.isKnown(BaseLexicon.java:152)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.BaseLexicon.ruleIteratorByWord(BaseLexicon.java:208)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustivePCFGParser.initializeChart(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:1343)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustivePCFGParser.parse(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:457)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParserQuery.parseInternal(LexicalizedParserQuery.java:258)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParserQuery.parse(LexicalizedParserQuery.java:536)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.parse(LexicalizedParser.java:301)
    at my.class.NounPhraseExtractionWithStanford$$anonfun$extractNounPhrases$3.apply(NounPhraseExtractionWithStanford.scala:28)
    at my.class.NounPhraseExtractionWithStanford$$anonfun$extractNounPhrases$3.apply(NounPhraseExtractionWithStanford.scala:27)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
    at my.class.NounPhraseExtractionWithStanford$.extractNounPhrases(NounPhraseExtractionWithStanford.scala:27)
    at my.class.HBaseDocumentProducerWithStanford$$anonfun$produceDocumentTokens$3.apply(HBaseDocumentProducerWithStanford.scala:104)
    at my.class.HBaseDocumentProducerWithStanford$$anonfun$produceDocumentTokens$3.apply(HBaseDocumentProducerWithStanford.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$mapValues$1$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:674)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$mapValues$1$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:674)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.unrollSafely(MemoryStore.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.putInBlockManager(CacheManager.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

In the source code I see that apparently because of many transient class variables of edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.BaseLexicon the SerDe performed during broadcast (using Kryo serializer) leaves BaseLexicon half-initialized.

I realize that developers of LexParser didn't had spark in mind when designing it but still I would greatly appreciate any hints on how I could use it in my scenario (with spark that is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible workaround, not 100% sure that it'll work:

```
class ParseSentence extends (List[HasWord] => WhateverParseReturns) with Serializable {
  def apply(sentence: List[HasWord]) = ParseSentence.parser.parse(sentence)
}

object ParseSentence {
  val parser = LexicalizedParser.loadModel(englishPCFG.ser.gz)
}

someSparkRdd.map(new ParseSentence)
```

This way `parser` shouldn't need to be serialized/deserialized because it isn't captured as a field of the function object.

Comment: It did work, almost! The class has to extend Serializable as well (or spark gives TaskNotSerializableException). And it would be nice if you could elaborate (or link) the trick with apply method in class. For those of you who are puzzled, the line can be written like this as well `someSparkRdd.map(sentence => new ParseSentence().aply(sentence))` which is syntactically not as nice as Alexeys code but possibly could explain what is going on there.

Comment: Added `Serializable`. There is no real trick here; `List[HasWord] => WhateverParseReturns` is just another way to write `Function1[List[HasWord], WhateverParseReturns]` and `Function1[A, B]` is a trait with an abstract `apply` method which `ParseSentence` implements.